# Split a string into math and into single words

Tags: python, split, latex, formula, words

I am using Python and would like to write a code, which splits a latex-code into several parts. 
I want to split the text at the |

```
Hello | the | formula | is |$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x) - \sum_{n=0} x^{n} $ | and | it | is | a | good | formula, since |$ \delta -\gamma  = \int \Omega dx $ |.
```

into single words and whole formulas. 
The result is supposed to look like this:

```
['Hello' , 'the' , 'formula' , 'is' , '$\int_{\delta}^{\gamma} - \sum_{\epsilon} x^{\epsilon}$' , 'and' ...]
```

So far I used the re.findall function, but it only extracts the math formulas.

Best regards

Edit: My question was not clear enough. The text I want to start with looks like Hello the formula is `$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)-...$` without any | signs. The | show where I want to split the text into different strings. Best regards

Comment: You can use `'some | string'.split('|')` if you just need to split on the pipe

Comment: My question was not clear enough. The text I want to start with looks like 'Hello the formula is $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)-...$' without any | signs. The | 
 show where I want to split the text into different strings. Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `re.findall`, use `re.split`:

```
s = "Hello | the | formula | is |$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x) - \sum_{n=0} x^{n} $ | and | it | is | a | good | formula, since |$ \delta -\gamma  = \int \Omega dx $ |."
import re
final_s = re.split('\s\|\s', s)
```

Output:

```
['Hello', 'the', 'formula', 'is', '$ \\int_{-\\infty}^{\\infty}f(x) - \\sum_{n=0} x^{n} $', 'and', 'it', 'is', 'a', 'good', 'formula, since', '$ \\delta -\\gamma  = \\int \\Omega dx $', '.']
```

Comment: My question was not clear enough. The text I want to start with looks like Hello the formula is $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)-...$ without any | signs. The | 
 show where I want to split the text into different strings. Best regards

Answer (score 0):

```
re.findall('\w+|\$[^\$]*\$', yourString)
```

should do what you want.